# Hard Drive won't mount in OS X 10.5

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mount, sata

So I have an internal 500GB Western Digital HDD, and it's formatted at NTFS, but it won't mount in OS X. Both Windows and Ubuntu Linux can read and write to it perfectly fine, but OS X says the file system is unreadable. I have used this hard drive before with OS X and it worked flawlessly, but now when I boot I get a "OS X cannot read this filesystem" error.

Answer (score 1):

Try repairing the partition in Linux or Windows and then attempting to mount on the Mac.  It's very likely that the Mac will refuse to mount a dirty partition, not knowing how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a problem with the driver. Try using [ntfs-3g for OS X](http://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/).

example:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/disk1s1 /Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

Mac OSX I'm pretty sure can only read NTFS and not write. So, give [this](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) a try. It is a preference pane built by Paragon and it allows you to mount the NTFS partitions needed.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here - please expand your answer, @roher4.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the comment now.

Answer (score 0):

Safely Eject the drive the last time you used it? I know that you've got to force a mount in linux if an NTFS drive wasn't safely dismounted in windows...